# Center 1 item in a row, but float other one to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using NgBootstrap with Bootstrap4 and would like to center the pagination into the middle of the page, but have the Page size dropdown on the right side.
I currently have this.

```
  <div class="d-flex">
    <ngb-pagination class="mx-auto"
      [collectionSize]="(total$ | async)!" [(page)]="globalListService.page" [pageSize]="globalListService.pageSize">
    </ngb-pagination>

    <select class="custom-select float-right" style="width: auto" name="pageSize" [(ngModel)]="globalListService.pageSize">
      <option [ngValue]="2">2 items per page</option>
      <option [ngValue]="4">4 items per page</option>
      <option [ngValue]="6">6 items per page</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

But as expected, the margin on the right still considers the space that the dropdown is taking. I want the pagination to be exactly centered

[image]

**Working solution:**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <ngb-pagination class="position-absolute"
                  [collectionSize]="(total$ | async)!" [(page)]="globalListService.page" [pageSize]="globalListService.pageSize">
  </ngb-pagination>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <select class="custom-select" style="width: auto" name="pageSize" [(ngModel)]="globalListService.pageSize">
    <option [ngValue]="2">2 items per page</option>
    <option [ngValue]="4">4 items per page</option>
    <option [ngValue]="6">6 items per page</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening cause both of them are in the same document flow. Using position absolute we can remove it from the document flow. Here I have showed an example:

1. Give your `<ngb-pagination>` an ID for eg. `my-pagination`.
2. In your `CSS` use these properties:

```
#my-pagination {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 2;
                    left: 50%;
                    right: 50%;
               }
```

Now no matter what the screen size your pagination is going to be in the center and won't be affected by margins of any other elements.

Comment: This does not work. It actually adds even more distance between the dropdown and the pagination.

Comment: @CraigArmstrong Hmm that's happening cause both of them are in the same `z-index` did you try using position `absolute` to remove it from the document flow?

Comment: @CraigArmstrong Here I edited my answer try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I combined your idea with some of my own css. I've added the answer to my original post

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div>
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <ngb-pagination class="mx-auto"
   [collectionSize]="(total$ | async)!" [(page)]="globalListService.page" 
   [pageSize]="globalListService.pageSize">
  </ngb-pagination>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
   <select class="custom-select " style="width: auto" name="pageSize" 
    [(ngModel)]="globalListService.pageSize">
     <option [ngValue]="2">2 items per page</option>
     <option [ngValue]="4">4 items per page</option>
     <option [ngValue]="6">6 items per page</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, and it unfortunately didn't work. The <select> element actually gets pushed down into its own row for some reason. So the pagination is perfectly centered, but the <select> is on the right, but below it.